# Jquery - $.(post) data response not consistent with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Jquery code:

```
var code = $('#code'),
     id = $('input[name=id]').val(),
     url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>mali_oglasi/mgl_check_paid';
     code.on('focusout', function(){
        var code_value = $(this).val();
        if(code_value.length != 16 ) {
            if ($('p[role=code_msg]').length != 0 ) $('p[role=code_msg]').remove() ;
            code.after('<p role=code_msg>Pogrešan kod je unešen.</p>');
        } else {
            if ($('p[role=code_msg]').length != 0 ) $('p[role=code_msg]').remove() ;
            $.post(url, {id : id, code : code_value}, function(data){
                if(data != 'TRUE'){
                    code.after('<p role=code_msg>Uneti kod je neispravan.</p>');
                } else {
                    code.after('<p role=code_msg>Status malog oglasa je promenjen.</p>');
                    code.after(create_image());
                    code.remove();
                }
        });
        }
     });
```

PHP (Codeigniter) code:

```
function mgl_check_paid()
    {
        $code = $this->input->post('code');
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        echo ($this->mgl->mgl_check_paid($code, $id)) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
    }
```

Problem is following: 
When code is sent and if it is correct, PHP part will echo **TRUE**, and JS will execute **ELSE** part (after post), but for some reason it is not doing that (it is executing the first part of the statment)? What is wrong with this code?

Comment: have you tried `if (data !== 'TRUE')` ?

Comment: do  $.post(url, {id : id, code : code_value}, function(data){
alert(data); and see what data is coming from server and verify if it's TRUE or anything else.

Comment: Alert is showing TRUE and a lot of white space before that. I guess I will have to trim it first.

Comment: use Firebug or Chrome developer tools' net tab to see the responses. You could also consider using json, which would allow you more flexiblity.

Comment: I am bit unfamiliar with JSON. How can I do this with JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an `exit` after echo statement in php code.

```
echo ($this->mgl->mgl_check_paid($code, $id)) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
exit;
```